# Why sub-menu getting opened automatically in WPF MENU?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a menu which contains submenu for few items. First time, submenu opens when i click on a menu-item. After that, the next submenu being opened without click, just on hover. I don't want other submenu to be opened without click.

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="0,-7,0,5">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <ContentPresenter  x:Name="mainMenuHeaderContainer" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,0,13" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#595959" BorderThickness=".5,0,0,0" Background="#32a3cf">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="#666" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#32a3cf"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="#32a3cf" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate2" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness=".5,0,.5,.5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid Margin="-1" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#32a3cf"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="menuHeaderContainer" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
                <!--<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                </Trigger>-->
                <!--<MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
                </MultiTrigger>-->
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>


    <Menu x:Name="menu_main_project" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">

                        <MenuItem Height="42" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}" Width="140">

                            <MenuItem.Header>
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="menuBarApplication" Fill="#32a3cf" Width="140" Height="4" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                                    <Image Source="/Resources/ico_application.png" Stretch="Fill" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10,2,0,0" Height="19" Width="22">
                                    </Image>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="APPLICATION_MENU" TextBlock.Foreground="#0e526a" Margin="4,0,0,0" Content="Application" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </MenuItem.Header>
                            <!--<MenuItem Header="Learner"  x:Name="menuItem_LearnerApplicationHome" Click="OnClick_LearnerApplicationHome"/>-->
                            <MenuItem Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" Header="DL" x:Name="menuItem_DLApplicationHome" Click="OnClick_DLApplicationHome" Foreground="#0e526a" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White"/>
                            <MenuItem Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" Header="Adjudication" x:Name="menuItem_Adjudication" Click="OnClick_AdjudicationHome" Foreground="#0e526a" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White"/>
                            <MenuItem Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" Header="Summary" x:Name="menuItem_Application_Summary" Click="OnClick_ApplicationSummaryHome" Foreground="#0e526a" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Width="105" Height="42" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
                            <MenuItem.Header>
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="menuBarCard" Fill="#32a3cf" Width="105" Height="4" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                                    <Image Source="/Resources/ico_card.png" Margin="20,2,0,0" Stretch="Fill" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="19" Width="22"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="CARD_MENU" Margin="4,0,0,0" Content="Card" TextBlock.Foreground="#0e526a" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </MenuItem.Header>
                            <MenuItem Header="Card" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}"  Name="menuItem_CardHome" Click="OnClick_CardkHome" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White" Foreground="#0e526a"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Summary" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" x:Name="menuItem_Card_Summary" Click="OnClick_CardSummaryHome" Foreground="#0e526a" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White"/>
<!-- Menu -->
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Width="105" Height="42" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
                            <MenuItem.Header>
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="menuBarStock" Fill="#32a3cf" Width="105" Height="4" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                                    <Image Source="/Resources/ico_stock.png" Margin="18,2,0,0" Stretch="Fill" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="19" Width="22"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="STOCK_MENU" Margin="4,0,0,0" Content="Stock" TextBlock.Foreground="#0e526a" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </MenuItem.Header>
                            <MenuItem Header="Stock" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" Name="menuItem_StockHome" Click="OnClick_StockHome" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White" Foreground="#0e526a"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Item" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" Name="menuItem_ItemHome" Click="OnClick_ItemHome" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White" Foreground="#0e526a"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Summary" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate2}" x:Name="menuItem_Stock_Summary" Click="OnClick_BoxSummaryHome" Foreground="#0e526a" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White"/>

                        </MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some code...so that we can take a look at what might be wrong.

Comment: And what is the issue in it? Do you want to open them on button_click?

Comment: I don't want other submenu to be opened without click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IsMouseOver`. Below is what I looked at when I ran into a similar issue.

[Making 'IsMouseOver' open submenu items consistently](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da54f9fc-068b-46fb-988f-b752d07ba1c5/making-ismouseover-open-submenu-items-consistently?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 0):

There'll be a better solution, but this'll be work too

Add your MenuItem attributes on xml

```
SubmenuOpened="MenuItem_SubmenuOpened" MouseEnter="MenuItem_MouseEnter"
```

and add to your code

```
bool open = true;
    private void MenuItem_SubmenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MenuItem)sender).IsSubmenuOpen = open;
        open = true;
    }
    private void MenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        open = false;
    }
```

When you click the MenuItem, SubMenuOpened event is triggered twice (one for hover, one for click).
On hover, The submenu is not opening, because of that bool. But on click, it triggers twice and second trigger is opening the submenu.

Sorry for my bad english.